# iphone XCode-Wifi connection

Tags: iphone, wifi

I am a beginner in iPhone development. I have a single static IP server in my company. I have one web service on that server which gets data from an intranet MSSQL server. I would like to get that data over WiFi to an iPad app, but only over our intranet.

Have any useful links or a sample project? I am using XCode 3.2.6.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is a simple web service consumption scenario, so I would start with consuming it using JSON as the transfer data format and using [NSUrlRequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

[Here is an article](http://petermcintyre.wordpress.com/2010/11/04/consume-json-rest-in-ios/) that walks you through everything you need to know in almost painful detail. It should get you where you wish to go.